# Most standard way to set configuration settings in a Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'm developing a Class Library / API and I need to store some global parameters that will be used by some classes. I thought about two main ways to do so (ignoring configuration files which I'd prefer not using in this case):

1) Specifying the parameters in a static class, like this:

```
// Stores and validates settings
ApiConfiguration.SetConfiguration("some values or class here");

var methods1 = new MyFirstApiMethods();
methods1.DoStuff(); // Internally uses static ApiConfiguration.

var methods2 = new MySecondApiMethods();
methods2.DoOtherStuff();  // Internally uses static ApiConfiguration.
```

2) Creating an instance of the configuration class and pass it to the classes, like this:

```
// Create an instance of the configuration class
var config = new ApiConfiguration();
config.ServerName = "some-server-name";

var methods1 = new MyFirstApiMethods(config);
methods1.DoStuff(); // Uses the supplied ApiConfiguration instance.

var methods2 = new MySecondApiMethods(config);
methods2.DoOtherStuff(); // Uses the supplied ApiConfiguration instance.
```

The fist option feels more natural for me, but I can think of some possible downsides (if the config is set in two places with different values, for example).

I want to know the possible downsides of each implementation and what is the most common way to do this in known projects of this nature.

Comment: I'd like to know why you discarded configurations files. Most of the libraries over there uses the web.config or its own file. Take into account that a change on a configuration will require a rebuild.

Comment: I don't really like the idea of clients having to include .dll.config files, but this is more some personal preference. Clients can (and should) store configuration items in their configuration files, read them and then supply them to the library.

Comment: Normally you take advantage of the existing app.config or web.config and use it. You just need to add required configuration items on the library documentation.

Comment: You're right, but in this particular case most parameters won't be generally stored in app or web.config because they will have to be collected from users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say #1 is the most common.  I know you said that you didn't want to use configuration files, but if you look at how .NET uses app.config I think you will see that a similar approach to #1 is taken.  You don't see instances of app.config settings being passed around to every method/function that needs to read a setting.  I normally do VB.NET, for which there is a static My.Settings class that basically achieves the same thing as your #1.

The biggest disadvantage I see to #2 (and probably why it is less common) is that the config class can get passed around a lot.  If only a small number of methods actually need to read the config it might be ok, but if many methods need to read the config it starts to become a headache.  In my opinion it also clutters up the method signatures.  Imagine a class deep in the library that needs to read the config; you may have to pass the config through several higher level classes just to pass it through to the class that needs it.

I'd recommend at least considering using app.config or web.config as either one of these already have built in functionality for this type of thing.

**EDIT**

I was waiting for Brannon to respond with an example, but since he hasn't I'll go ahead and chime in.  IOC containers are great tools to help with dependency injection, but I wouldn't dream of introducing one just for a settings class.  If you were already using one, that might be a different story.  Lets suppose that you were already using an IOC container and wanted to use it for your config class.  That means you still have method signatures that look like:

```
Function Add (FirstNumber, SecondNumber, Config)
```

Admittedly that example is a stretch, but you get the idea.  The IOC container will resolve your Config dependency (it will create the config class for you), but you still have the config as a parameter to each method/constructor that needs it.

To be honest some of it comes down to personal preference.  Keep in mind that VS/.NET uses #1 out of the box when you use app.config.  I know that static classes are frequently frowned upon and rightfully so in many cases, but I think that settings/config classes are exceptions to the rule.

Comment: Thanks! I will consider using config files (plus the first approach), since everyone is pointing that way. I'll read more about it and run some tests to see if it suits all of my needs.

Comment: I entirely disagree with the first answer given. #2 is the absolute right way to do it -- in conjunction with a nice IoC container of course. You won't be passing anything around. Rather, the injector will take care of that for you and you will be able to unit test with settings.

Comment: @Brannon could you post an example, please?

Comment: @Meryovi are you familiar with IOC containers?

Comment: @CaseyWilkins not quite, but I have read a bit and understand the concept.

Comment: @CaseyWilkins I too think that DI / IoC are too much for a single settings class that is likely to always have only two properties. On a side note, I think that in this case IoC is something that the implementer of the API would use, not me as the creator. I just have to provide IoC friendly classes.

Comment: @Meryovi, I think that is a sensible approach.